# Android: Camera Error - > Cannot connect to the camera

Tags: android, camera, android-manifest

I have a problem with my app. Before this, if I want to use camera function, the camera will run well. But today, if I want to use the camera function, it states that "Cannot connect to the camera". I don't why. Below is my code:

```
            btnCameraBefore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 7);

                }
            });

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            imgAttachBefore.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }

    public void EnableRuntimePermission(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(TaskUpdateBefore.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
        {

            Toast.makeText(TaskUpdateBefore.this,"CAMERA permission allows us to Access CAMERA app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TaskUpdateBefore.this,new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestPermissionCode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) {

        switch (RC) {

            case RequestPermissionCode:

                if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(TaskUpdateBefore.this,"Permission Granted, Now your application can access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(TaskUpdateBefore.this,"Permission Canceled, Now your application cannot access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: is your app getting crashed or you are getting dailog also you said it was working before so is that on same device or any other device?

Comment: at android emulator

Comment: Your app may crash for many reason. better to see LogCat. post the error. then any one can help you...

Comment: Before it work but not working now... what change you made, we don't know and haven't mention. so see logcat and post that... or properly describe your problem.

Comment: Make sure that you released the camera appropriately. Not releasing the camera can cause it to run into this state on a device.